# Splitting string after specific sequence of characters using regex (Python)

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of a string of messages I extracted from a text file, all of which look like this:

`s = 'Nov 1 11 45 AM Jane Doe hi`

And I need it to look like this:

`'Nov 1 11 45 AM, Jane Doe, hi'`

I have this as my code, because first I am working on splitting the time and name, and then I plan to work on splitting the name and message separately:

```
rx = re.compile(r'\B(AM|PM)\s')
r=rx.split(s)
```

But it prints this:

`'Nov 1 11 45 ', 'AM', 'Jane Doe hi'`

Any ideas on how to split AFTER a delimiter?

Thank you!

Comment: In your example, there's a comma inserted after 'Doe', before 'hi' - what rule should that follow?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) like so:

```
import re
s = 'Nov 1 11 45 AM Jane Doe hi'

# Partial solution:
foo = re.sub(r'(AM|PM)', '\\1,', s)
print(foo)
# Nov 1 11 45 AM, Jane Doe hi

# Complete solution:
bar = re.sub(r'(AM|PM)(\s+\S+\s+\S+)', '\\1,\\2,', s)
print(bar)
# Nov 1 11 45 AM, Jane Doe, hi
```

`r'(AM|PM)'` : match either `AM` or `PM` and store it in the match variable `\1`, which is then escaped again (`\\1`) and used in the replacement string.
`r'(AM|PM)(\s+\S+\s+\S+)'` : match either `AM` or `PM`, followed by one or more whitespace characters, then one or more non-whitespace characters, then the same again. Store the results in match variables `\1` and `\2`. Note that match variables are numbered according to the position of the opening parenthesis, from left to right.

Answer (score 1):

Here an example to get the line in two parts: the date, and the rest
And an example to get 3 parts: the date, the name (2 words), the rest is the message

```
import re
s = 'Nov 1 11 45 AM Jane Doe hi to all of you'

rx = re.compile(r'(.*AM|PM)(.*)')
r=rx.findall(s)
print(r)
```

result is:

```
[('Nov 1 11 45 AM', ' Jane Doe hi to all of you')]
```

This example shows how to get 3 parts: the date, the name (2 words), the rest is the message

```
rx = re.compile(r'(.*AM|PM)(.+? .+?) (.*)')
r=rx.findall(s)
print(r)
```

result is:

```
[('Nov 1 11 45 AM', ' Jane Doe', 'hi to all of you')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need to split after multiple occurrences as well, and you're not splitting after 'Doe' or before 'hi':

```
s = 'Want to split AM with some PM and more'
split_after = ['AM', 'PM']
rx = re.compile(rf'(?<=({"|".join(split_after)}))[^\b]')
result = ', '.join(x for x in rx.split(s) if x not in split_after)
```

Result will be:

```
'Want to split AM, with some PM, and more'
```